# Migrate data from TFS 2010 to TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration

I want to migrate TFS data from TFS 2010 (SP 1) that uses SQL Server 2008 R2 to TFS 2017 that uses SQL Server 2016. Is there any way to migrate data from TFS 2010 to TFS 2017?

Comment: This worked for you?

Comment: How was the transition (smooth-hard) and did it work at the end ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot upgrade directly from TFS 2010 to TFS 2017, but need to go through TFS 2013 Update 5 (see below).

[image: TFS compatibility]

You can read more [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/01/23/tfs-2017-update-1-rc-available/).

I would recommend setting up a new server with SQL Server 2014, where you can migrate your databases using SQL backup. Then first install TFS 2013.5 followed by TFS 2017.2 and finally updating SQL Server to 2016 (See [TFS support for SQL Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements)). I suggest doing a trial migration first to validate that things work and to know how long production downtime is needed for the actual migration.